# Fixed to left on horizontal scroll

Tags: css, fixed

I have navigation bar that is fixed to the top of the page when user scroll down.
I also need it to be fixed to the top left corner of the right block when user scroll horizontally. How to do this? Thanks for any advice.

CSS:

```
#box {
   margin: 0 auto;
}

#content {
   height: 500px;
   width: 1000px;
}

#left {
   max-width: 20%;
   display: inline-block;
   background: #aaa;
}

#right {
   max-width: 80%;
   display: inline-block;
   background: red;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
}

nav {
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   height: 50px;
   background: #666;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="box">
    <div id="content">
        <div id="left">LEFT</div>
        <div id="right">
            <nav>
               Some text        
            </nav>
            RIGHT
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/deguac8y/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery to detect scrolling horizontally and by using class you can switch between having a fixed position nav to absolute position nav when horizontal scrolling is detected without losing the current scroll position.

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/deguac8y/2/)

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
    var detectScroll = 0;
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var documentScrollLeft = $(document).scrollLeft();
        if (detectScroll != documentScrollLeft) {
            detectScroll = documentScrollLeft;
            $('nav').addClass('notFixed');
            var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
            $('nav').css('top',scrollTop);  
        } else {
            $('nav').removeClass('notFixed');
            $('nav').css('top','auto');  
        }
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    margin:0
}
#box {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#content {
    height: 500px;
    width: 1000px;
}
#left {
    max-width: 20%;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #aaa;
}
#right {
    max-width: 80%;
    display: inline-block;
    background: red;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
nav {
    position: fixed;
    height: 50px;
    background: #666;
}
nav.notFixed {
    position:absolute;
    top:auto;
    left:auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box">
    <div id="content">
        <div id="left">LEFT</div>
        <div id="right">
            <nav>Some text</nav>RIGHT</div>
    </div>
</div>
```